# MSSQL using PDO to connect

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect to a mssql server on my mac through pdo_dblib. I have the freetds.conf updated to the host I want to connect. My phpinfo tells me that I have all the driver hooked up and good to go. Below is the code that I wrote to test if I can connect to the server.

```
<?php
  $servername = "IP";
  $port = "port";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $myDB = "database";
  try {
     $conn = new PDO("dblib:dbname=$myDB;host=$servername:$port", "$username", "$password");

     // set the PDO error mode to exception
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     echo "Connected successfully"; 
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

However I get an error:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)

I tried using SQL Developer to connect to the mssql server and it worked. I have been trying to solve this problem for a whole day. What might be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer!

You have to uncomment TDS version protocol in /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/etc/freetds.conf.

Found the solution in [Why won't my server connect to a remote MSSQL server using PHP mssql_connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215063/why-wont-my-server-connect-to-a-remote-mssql-server-using-php-mssql-connect)

but why do I have to do this...no idea...wish some one could give some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the variables in the connection string -

```
 $conn = new PDO("dblib:dbname=$myDB;host=$servername:$port", $username, $password);
```

Comment: Are you sure the driver is loaded @BillCheng?

Comment: This is in what my phpinfo page says: PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, dblib. I believe this means that the driver is loaded right?

Comment: what happens when you run it in terminal?

Comment: Yep, looks like the driver is loaded @BillCheng. Double-check all of your variables to make sure you don't have spelling or capitalization errors.